# How to properly send an Image from React to Java?

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, base64, bufferedimage

I'm making a program that captures webcam images and I need to be able to send them to a backend for text detection and image recognition.

I'm using react webcam for the screenshots. Component is declared like this:

```
    <Webcam
      mirrored="false"
      audio={false}
      screenshotFormat="image/jpeg"
      ref={props.webcam}
      style={{
        marginLeft: "auto",
        marginRight: "auto",
        display: "block",
        paddingTop: "10px",
        paddingBottom: "10px",
      }}
    />
```

then, I invoke `webcamRef.current.getScreenshot()` to get the Image as a Base64 encoding. bytes are sent to a java backend with the following logic:

```
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", props.image);
  formData.append("user", props.user);

  axios
    .post("http://localhost:8080/api/storeImage", formData, {
      headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/formdata" },
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      throw err;
    });
```

Everything works fine up to this point. Problem arises when I try to create an ImageBuffer from the java backend:

Contoller:

```
@PostMapping("/api/storeImage")
@ResponseBody
public String storeImage(@RequestParam("file") String file, @RequestParam Long user) throws IOException, InvalidDniException {
    return service.storeImage(file, user);
}
```

Service:

```
public String storeImage(String source, Long user) throws IOException, InvalidDniException {
            byte[] decodedSource = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(source);
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(decoded)); <-- this returns null ...
```

I need the BufferedImage to crop and extract information from the captured screenshot. Every answer I've found on similar questions do not seem to work here.

Comment: Is your parameter name correct? In sender you have "file" but in receiver you have "source"

Comment: What kind of information are you trying to extract?

Comment: @AbishekStephen names are correct, I edited the post with the controller logic to reflect the parameter name change.

Comment: Should it be form data or multipartfile? In download mostly octetstream is used. Shouldn't the "file" parameter be byte[] instead of String?

Comment: @ControlAltDel Any text and faces that can be detected. The logic is for a KYC Identity Verification, and users are asked to take a picture of their 'DNI' (Argentinian National Identity Card)

Comment: @AbishekStephen I don't know what octetstream is, kinda new to this. I've tried both form data and multipartFile with no successful results.

Changing String to byte[] in the controller leads to this exception:
org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "undefined"

Comment: Well the error is now throwing for your "user" parameter as it is trying to convert from String to Long. Check if @RequestParam("user") should be present

Comment: @AbishekStephen you are right, I screwed up the user type when making the example for this post. Changed the value to Long and the controller is getting the byte[] properly, but still ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(decoded)) is returning null. :(

Comment: Ok let's check the value of the image data in each step. Can you confirm if the object is not null starting from the Controller itself? Debug and let me know.

Comment: @AbishekStephen yep, data is fine even after it gets decoded, problem arises when I try to create the ImageBuffer.

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace or error you're receiving. I can't process the cause of the error

Comment: @AbishekStephen thats actually my problem, BufferedImage is not throwing any kind of exception, it just returns null. I've wrapped the code in a try catch statement, but I'm still getting no error.

Comment: Well that will be extremely difficult to debug. Can you show a sample of what "source" and "decodedSource" contain?

Comment: @AbishekStephen Turns out I had to remove this: data:image/jpeg;base64 from the String received, can't believe it was that simple. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: Phew. Glad it worked out. Can you mark my reply as answer? It will be a great help.

Comment: @AbishekStephen for sure, post the answer and I will mark it. I think its not possible to mark comments as answers.

Comment: I see. You can answer your own question and mark it as correct one. I did not find the solution but only gave suggestions to your problem so you answer and mark it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to remove this prefix: data:image/jpeg;base64 from the String received.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).